# Working with excel and r2xcel in R

Tags: r

I created a function that takes an excel file and splits it into smaller files using r2excel package. Basically, the function reads an excel file which contains all the students in our district, and creates individual files for each teacher in a school (e.g. class list). It seems to work fine in one excel file, however, when I tested on a different one, it still produced some files, but then suddenly it stopped. My solution was to remove some of the rows that causes the problem, and then rerun the function again. But this is only a temporary solution.
Below is the error I received.

Error in .jnew("java/io/File", file) : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Here is my code:

```
  df <- read.csv("bigfile.csv")
extract <- function(name){
  temp_df <- subset(df, `Teacher Name` == name)
  temp_df <- temp_df[order(temp_df$Class, temp_df$`Student Name`),]
       wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx") 
    sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Class List")
             xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet, temp_df, fontColor="darkblue", row.names=FALSE, startCol=1,fontSize=11)
             xlsx.addLineBreak(sheet,0)
filename <- paste(unique(temp_df$`School Name`), unique(temp_df$`Teacher Name`),sep=" ")
filename <- paste(filename, " 2D.xlsx", sep="")
            saveWorkbook(wb, filename)  
}
lapply(unique(df$`Teacher Name`), extract)
```

Can someone please explain to me what the error implies as I am not familiar with r2excel  or java? Is there something wrong with my excel file or did I not implement r2excel correctly? I am using the latest R and Rstudio. Thank you

Comment: Can you upload the File to something like dropbox or similar? Can you also show a minimal code snippet?

Comment: I'm having difficulty matching your description to that code. I don't see any "reading" of an excel file, rather it appears your attempting to serially create separate files. The other problem I have is that the r2excel package on GitHub doesn't have any of those functions listed in its Index page. Are you sure you are giving us an accurate picture of your setup? I'm guessing that you are actually using the `xlsx` package. Did you actually write this code????

Comment: r2excel is dependent on xlsx package...so some of the functions in xlsx are also in r2excel.

Comment: Can you also provide a few lines from your csv file? Preferably some which show the described error?

Comment: My excel file includes these variables: School Name, Teacher Name, Student, Gender, ESL, Class. It Looks like this: School A, Jane D, John D, F, Yes, Math.

Comment: If you just use `read.csv` with a file name then there will NOT be a column named `Teacher Name`. R sanitizes its column names so there _might_ be a column named `Teacher.Name`.  If you are using `subset` then I would think it should be unnecessary in the expression for a column name unless it had spaces in it .. .. .. which the code above would not produce.   `</p>` Unless you respond substantively to the requests for an actual example I predict this question will get closed. Do NOT use comments to improve or clarify the question. Use the edit button.